# Missing support library v7 23

Tags: android, android-support-library

In my Android studio I am only able to see the support libraries for the version 25.0.0 but my compile SDK version is 23 when I try to add `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.4` I get an error message that

```
Error:(27, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.4
```

but as per the SDK manager it shows that I have installed all the support libraries.

On top of that I am unable to locate the `v7:23.0.4` libraries in the menu

`File => Project Structure => Dependencies`

Here are the screenshots

[image]

[image]

My Questions

1. Why am I unable to see the support libraries for the version v7:23.0.4 ?
2. If the support library is not installed how come it does not show in my SDK Manager ?

**EDIT 1**

**Build.gradle(Module.app)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appnotic.quicknotes"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'
}
```

**EDIT 2**
[image]

Comment: about question 2, what you see as "installed" is the repository, not the library

Comment: @lelloman How do I install the missing repositories then ? I haven't found any option for it

Comment: I don't think you're missing the repository, could you post you module build.gradle?

Comment: @lelloman I have posted it.

Comment: thanks but i don't see com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.4 there...?

Comment: @lelloman I have updated the the question, please see the 3rd screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) it is not available from the repository, why? I don't know, but it is not the latest one for version 23, try `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1` instead

2) you don't install the libraries with the SDK manager, that only install the source where gradle get the library from, the library itself gets downloaded when you build

I tried with 23.0.4 and could not get it, with 23.2.1 yes. If you can get version 25.0.0 it means that the repository is installed, maybe the gradle project is messed up somehow. Try to delete the project iml file and .idea folder and recreate it.

Comment: Nope I am still getting an error with `com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1`

Comment: Ok i updated the answer, just to be sure it works with 25.0.0 right?

Comment: I just missed the appcompat and now it is working fine